# When offloading a hook implementation to another function, which function should be documented as "Implements..."?

Tags: 7, hooks

Can a function like `_menu_block_block_configure()` be documented as
*Implements hook_block_configure()*?

It initially threw me off to see an internal function (with underscore prefix) documented as a hook implementation, but if the actual work is being done here, then there is some sense to it.

Is this the proper way to document it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes, it's fine and widespread too!

It might look kind of unorthodox, but it's just offloading the bulk of the hook implementation to an include to keep the main .module file smaller.

A lot of other contributed modules do this too, for example the  *Display Suite* module, the Views module, and a bunch of others too.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I do know why one would offload in this way; it was a documentation question. Anyhoo, that's what I figured. And, by the way, I'm certainly not in the habit of second guessing established maintainers like Dave Reid (in the case of *Menu Block*); I just wanted to confirm that this is the norm before I follow suit. Thanks again and cheers -

Comment: I don't know if this is should be considered an established norm, or rather a matter of taste. At least I don't think it is documented that this is the "correct" behavior. Personally, I would prefer to label the actual hook implementation with "Implements hook_*()", but choose a somewhat distinct wording for the helper function. E.g. "Called by hook_*()". But I guess why not just do what others do..

Comment: @donquixote - "If a million people do a stupid thing, it's still a stupid thing." :) Thanks for your input. I agree that it isn't necessarily a *good* way, and would prefer something more accurately descriptive. Why not describe what you are actually doing, after all? But it also makes some sense that these undocumented "norms" - what most people do - would be considered the most acceptable alternative to a written standard because, well, popular usage is often how standards become standards in the first place.